Помогите разъяснить работу метода get

Есть словарь my_dict = {'a':500, 'b':5874, 'c': 560,'d':400, 'e':5874, 'f': 20}.
Необходимо вывести три ключа с наибольшим значением.

В интернете нашел решение такое:
result = sorted(my_dict, key = my_dict.get, reverse=True)[:3]

Результат работы: ['b', 'e', 'c'].
Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает key=my.dict.get? Методу же необходим аргумент, да и вообще он выводит значение ключа... Почему результат работы именно такой?

Передается ссылка на метод get, чтобы внутри функции sorted он мог быть вызван. Почитайте теорию про функции высшего порядка (для любого языка).

"да и вообще он выводит значение ключа" - ну да, этот код и сортирует по убыванию значений, а потом берет три первых ключа (у которых как раз и получаются максимальные значения)

@егор Ваш прошлый вопрос получил подробное разъяснение, однако ответ до сих пор не принят.

Итак, давайте проанализируем ваше выражение
sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get, reverse=True)[:3]

  (причем my_dict = {'a':500, 'b':5874, 'c': 560, 'd':400, 'e':5874, 'f': 20}).

Что делает стандартная функция sorted() для словаря? Ее интересуют только ключи словаря, т.е. она будет сортировать только ключи. (Значения ключей она просто игнорирует.)
Таким образом, sorted(my_dict) возвратила бы список ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'].

Метод .get() возвращает из словаря значение ключа, который задан как аргумент.
Например, my_dict.get('b') возвращает 5874.
Это почти то же самое, что и my_dict['b']. Разница здесь не играет никакой роли.

Что делает ключевой параметр key=my_dict.get?
Он обозначает, что мы будем сортировать элементы (в нашем случае ключи словаря) не по значениям самих элементов — сначала к каждому элементу будет применена функция my_dict.get, т.е. сделается
my_dict.get('a')     # результат:  500
my_dict.get('b')     # результат: 5874
my_dict.get('c')     # результат:  560
my_dict.get('d')     # результат:  400
my_dict.get('e')     # результат: 5874
my_dict.get('f')     # результат:   20

и получится «оценка» для каждого элемента (ключа словаря):
элемент    оценка 
-----------------
  'a'        500
  'b'       5874
  'c'        560
  'd'        400
  'e'       5874
  'f'         20

и после этого начнется сортировка ключей 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' и 'f' по их оценкам.

Но эта сортировка будет не по возрастанию оценок, а обратно, по убыванию, потому что использован ключевой параметр reverse=True (слово reverse значит обратно):
элемент    оценка 
-----------------
  'b'       5874
  'e'       5874
  'c'        560
  'a'        500
  'd'        400
  'f'         20

Значит, получим список
['b', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'f']


Но нас интересуют только первые 3 элемента этого списка, потому еще сделаем из него срез из элементов с индексами 0, 1 и 2, т.е. от 0 (включительно) до 3 (не включая), что записывается как [0:3], или короче [:3].
Получим список ['b', 'e', 'c'].



result = sorted(my_dict, key = my_dict.get, reverse=True)[:3]

Может так понятней будет. Это по сути тоже самое, что использовать в качестве ключа сортировки key такую анонимную функцию:
key = lambda x: my_dict.get(x)

То есть мы просто преобразуем ключ словаря в значение. Питон позволяет такие вещи записывать короче, вместо lambda x: func(x) можно написать просто func и это будет работать точно так же.
